# Pegar a imagem de um Json

Tags: json

Bom dia! Sou nova em javascript e estou tentando colocar a imagem de um JSON do site da bing e colocar no meu body porém não estou conseguindo retorna o seguinte erro:

> Failed to load access-control-allow-origin:
>   https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=pt-BR:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. (anonymous) @ test.html:30
>   test.html:35 erro de conexão

É a primeira vez que consumo api podem me ajudar por favor ? Para pegar somente a imagem preciso criar uma chave de desenvolvedor ? segue meu código:

```
function getData(url) { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest() 

      req.open('GET', url) 
      req.onload = function () {

        if (req.status === 200) { 
          resolve(req.response)
        } else {
          reject(req.status, req.statusText) 
        }
      }
      req.onerror = function () { 
        reject("erro de conexão")

      }

       req.send() 
     })
  }

  const catchImage = document.getElementById("body") 

  getData 

  const url = getData("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=pt-BR").then(function(response)
  {
    const jsonResponse =JSON.parse(response.images.url)
    console.log(response)
    catchImage.innerHTML = ""
    for (const url of jsonResponse["url"]) {
        catchImage.innerHTML = catchImage.innerHTML + "<img src='" + images.url +  "' />"
      console.log(url)
    }
  }, function(error) { console.log(error)})
```

Comment: Você pode usar uma das extensões para o chrome (para desenvolvimento): Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * CORS Toggle Estas extensões desabilitam a segurança do chrome com relação a comunicação de hosts diferentes sem a definição de autorização no cabeçalho (como feita pela função header() ). A do seu exemplo não tem acesso externo ou seja, o seu front-end que consome a API deve estar no mesmo host(IP + porta) da API, mais como a api não e sua então não vai funcionar.